# Can no longer resize C drive partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

After deleting my Ubuntu partition and putting the unallocated space back in the C drive in Windows, I am no longer able to see the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option anymore when trying to dual boot Ubuntu.

Originally, I was able to partition the C drive using Gparted, but now, it appears that Ubuntu no longer recognizes the C drive, and it tries by default to install Ubuntu on my recovery (D) drive. I read in other posts that this is caused by hard drive no longer having a logical partition, but it seems weird that when I first dual booted, I was able to use the Gparted tool to create a partition on the C drive. Now, even when I manually create an empty partition in Windows, Ubuntu does not recognize it either.

I am trying to dual boot Ubunt 16.10 and Windows 10. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Here are the outputs of "sudo lsblk" and "sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda":

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1  29.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  29.8G  0 part /cdrom
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0   1.4G  1 loop /rofs
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda4   8:4    0 902.2G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   260M  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0    27G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   875M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda1   8:1    0   650M  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0   450M  0 part 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BD29FBA9-B2D7-4727-A310-46279AA7A753

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1333247    1331200   650M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     1333248    1865727     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1865728    2127871     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     2127872 1894123736 1891995865 902.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  1894127616 1895919615    1792000   875M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  1895919616 1896841215     921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  1896841216 1953513471   56672256    27G Microsoft basic data
```

EDIT2: Output of gparted command:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  683MB   682MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      683MB   955MB   273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      955MB   1089MB  134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      1089MB  970GB   969GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      970GB   971GB   918MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
 6      971GB   971GB   472MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
 7      971GB   1000GB  29.0GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, msftdata
```

EDIT3: Here is the screenshot of the Gparted GUI:

[image]

Comment: Please show `sudo lsblk`, `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

Comment: Will do. Give me a sec to boot live into Ubuntu.

Comment: Added the outputs.

Comment: It is a GPT partitioned disk. Did you shut down Windows completely before rebooting (Windows 10 need special care to actually shut down)? Did you boot the computer is UEFI mode? Is Gparted happy do display the partitions?

Comment: Yes, I did shut it down. I also included the gparted command. The Ubuntu installer wanted to do the installation on the 29 GB partition (the D drive) but was unable to recognize the C drive (the 970 GB one).

Comment: If you boot into a live session and run Gparted, does it let you shrink the 950 GB partition and make a new partition formatted Ext4?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. There's an exclamation mark next to the partition, and the slider doesn't appear to work....

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by disabling fast boot on Windows. It looks like the issue did not have to do with the filesystem or partition at all.